# How do I prove the probability mass function of the binomial distribution has only one peak?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Suppose $X \sim Bin(n,p)$.

How do I show that the distribution has only one peak? That is, the probability mass function of $X$ is increasing before the peak, and decreasing after the peak?

For large values of $n$, I have used the central limit theorem to show that it follows a 'bell' shape, and therefore has only one peak.

However, I am having difficulty proving the same for small values of $n$.

Comment: Investigate the behaviour of $P(X=k+1)/P(X=k)$. In particular, compare this ratio with $1$.

Comment: This method can be used to show that there exists a peak, however how do I show that that's the only peak and the distribution does not have another peak elsewhere?

Comment: @kengchi If you get a unique value of $k$ ...

Answer (score 3):

By "peak" I assume you mean local maximum?

The analysis will be the same as for the global maximum, though, because when you have found that

$$
\frac{ P(X = k+1)}{P(X = k)} = \left(\frac{n-k}{k+1} \right)\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)
$$
and then find that for example that
$$
\frac{ P(X = k+1)}{P(X = k)} > 1 \Leftrightarrow k < p(n+1) - 1
$$
Then this shows that $ P(X = k)$ is increasing *at every* $k < p(n+1) - 1$,